# How do I make form entries mirror eachother?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, forms, input

Hi so I am working with angular2 javascript for my django app and I was wondering if there was any way that I could make my two form entries mirror eachother?

This is what I have so far:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="price_level.price_point[1].edit_price_per_case" name="price_per_case1" type="text" min="0" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" required style="width: 65px;">


<span ng-show="price_level.edit">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" min="0" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" 
        name="price_per_case0" ng-model="price_level.price_point[0].edit_price_per_case"
        ng-required='price_level.edit' style="width: 65px;">
  </span>
```

I would like it so that when I enter the top input it auto fills the bottom input or even vice versa.

Comment: is this really Angular 2+ or old angular js?

Comment: I believe it might be angular 2? I remember it being noted somewhere that it was angular 2. This is a project handed to me to revive from 3 years ago ahah.

Comment: it is angular js and you've already got an answer down below. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same model for each of them, e.g. `price_level.price_point[1].edit_price_per_case` on each elements.

An alternative is to use `ng-change` event and mirror values on change:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="price_level.price_point[1].edit_price_per_case" ng-change="mirror(price_level.price_point[1].edit_price_per_case)" name="price_per_case1" type="text" min="0" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" required style="width: 65px;">

<span ng-show="price_level.edit">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" min="0" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" name="price_per_case0" ng-model="price_level.price_point[0].edit_price_per_case" ng-change="mirror(price_level.price_point[0].edit_price_per_case)" ng-required='price_level.edit' style="width: 65px;">
</span>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.mirror = function(source) {
    $scope.price_level.price_point[0].edit_price_per_case = source;
    $scope.price_level.price_point[1].edit_price_per_case = source;
};
```

Comment: Hi, should this change it instantly? I am trying to get it to change as I type in the first entry as there is a save button that is disabled until both inputs are entered. This process is repeated many times so I am trying to save one step.

Comment: Updated my answer. Not the perfect solution but idk why the previous solution does not work. I have created a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/60091/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been going at this for hours hahaha.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can mark it as "solved / helpful answer".